# Copy an object derived from an abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, copy, abstract-class

I have an abstract base class named *component*.
It has derived non-abstract classes like *resistor*, *generator* etc...

In my *circuit* class, I have an heterogenous `std::vector<sim::component*>` named `component_list`, which I use to handle all the components inserted in the circuit.

Then I have the following function :

```
void circuit::insert(sim::component& comp, std::vector<sim::node*> nodes)
```

In the function definition, I want to copy the component named `comp`
in order to insert a pointer to it in my component_list
(so that I can manage its lifetime)

I tried something along those lines :

```
sim::component *copy = new sim::component(comp)
```

but of course, sim::component is abstract and I can't instanciate it

**How can I make a copy of the object, which real class is unknown at compile-time ?**

Comment: Perhaps a `virtual` clone function?

Comment: Could work, but it feels like I shouldn't need to change the classes to achieve that... Well maybe I have no choice ? Or maybe it could be done using a template version of `insert` ?? (just popped in my head)

Comment: If you cannot instantiate `component` how are you passing reference to it?

Comment: @KillzoneKid It's not a reference to a component I pass, but a reference to a base (instantiable) class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One traditional way to solve it is to let the objects clone themselves, plus a bit of CRTP.

I. First, you make your abstract class clonable:

```
struct Component {
    virtual Component *clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Component() {}
};
```

Now, every Component should define its own implementation of `clone()`.

II. Which is easily automated via CRTP:

```
template<class Concrete> struct CompBase: Component {
    Component *clone() const {
        return new Concrete(static_cast<Concrete const &>(*this));
    }
    virtual ~CompBase() {}
};

struct Generator: CompBase<Generator>;  // already has clone() defined
```

Note that I've used plain pointers in the example, though it is generally recommended to use more smart analogs. `std::unique_ptr` would fit quite nice, along with `std::make_unique`.

Which creates another opportunity: with `unique_ptr` you can even forget about cloning and simply pass unique_ptrs as objects, each one with its own concrete class instance inside, and store them in a vector.

Comment: I can't fully understand step 2. Would you have any good ressources explaining CRTP in detail ? thanks

Comment: Your implementation of CRTP fails to compile. You need to statically downcast 'this'.

Comment: Thank you, fixed.

Comment: Can someone check this actually works plz ? I can't get it to compile :/

Comment: @Magix Now it does (SO's Android app is practically useless). As for the CRTP, you can start, for instance, with Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern